# new Date().getTime() in c#

Tags: c#

Is That any c# function can replace this javascript function ?

Js

```
new Date().getTime();
```

I have create a function , but the number of value is different .

c#

```
public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime OLDtime= new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - OLDtime;
        return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

My Js function return 1372412348889 , but my c# only return 1372412347.0 , the c# returns value is less 3 digit from behind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getTime()` returns the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch. Your C# code is obtaining the number of *seconds* since the unix epoch.

You want to use [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds) instead of `TotalSeconds`.

Also, while it won't actually change the behaviour of the code, it would be more logical for your `OLDtime` variable (which I'd make a static readonly variable called `UnixEpoch`) to explicitly use `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

(As an aside, you might also want to use my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) framework which makes all of this a little cleaner.)

Comment: @Clystian: Or more usefully, nodatime.org - the source code isn't as useful as the documentation etc :) Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

JS timestamp (new Date().getTime()) returns **miliseconds**, C# (DateTime.Now) - seconds